# Automating google sheets via a script to send emails onedit to email on the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I amu sing the script below to send emails to email addresses inputted into specific columns when yes is inputted into a specific column.

One of the issues that I am having with this code is that i am not sure how I can send emails to more than two recepients at a time.

Furthermore this script does not work on sheets linked to google forms. After doing research i have found that the reason the script does not work is beacuse the script won`t run on onedit triggers but wil only run on timed triggers when linked to google Forms.

Please could someone accomplish the above.

```
EmailScript() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Repairs");
  // Sets "range" from A2 (2,1) to Bottom right cell of sheet (MaxRow,MaxColumn)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows()-1,sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var data = range.getValues()
  var activeRng,activeCell,columnToCheck,editedColumn,editedRow,newValue,sh,ss,valueToTestFor;//Define variables without assigning a value


  //USER INPUT
    columnToCheck = 9 ;//Column A is 1
    valueToTestFor = "Y"
  //END OF USER INPUT

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the active spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getActiveSheet();//Get the active sheet tab
  activeRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();//Get the active range
  activeCell = activeRng.getCell(1, 1);//Get the first cell in the active range
  newValue = activeCell.getValue();//Get the new value in the cell that was just edited
  editedColumn = activeCell.getColumn();//Get the column of the cell that was just edited
  editedRow = activeCell.getRow();//Get the row of the cell that was just edited

  if (editedColumn !== columnToCheck) {//Only run the code if the column to monitor is the correct one   
  return;

}

// Loops through data, 0 to the "length" of the data, set above (dictated by range), with i to be each row number with each loop, and row[X] representing Column X for row i.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

// Setting all variables for email messages
// Column A = row[0], Column B = row[1],C2,D3,E4,F5,G6,H7,I8,J9,K10,L11,M12,N13,O14,P15,Q16,R17,S18,T19,U20,V21,W22,X23 
    var row = data[i];

    var firstname = row[0];
    var email = row[1];
    var email2 = row [2];
    var email3 = row [4];
    var emailstatus = row[13]
    var emailPattern = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|aero|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|name|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel)\b/;
    var validEmailAddress = emailPattern.test(email); 

    if (newValue === valueToTestFor && emailstatus != "EMAIL_SENT") {    

        var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
        + "<P>Dear " + firstname + ","
        + "<br /><br />"
        +" Your device has been repaired"
        + "<br /><br />"    
        + "Regards"
        + "<br /><br />" 
        + "Test"
        + "<br /><br />"
        + "</HTML></BODY>";      
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to:email, 
        cc:email2,
        bbc:email3,
        subject:"Device Repair",
        htmlBody: message});   

   sheet.getRange(i+2,10).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");   

    } 
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Range is not defined.

Comment: Please could you expand on what you mean

Comment: @ruben The question is: On the spreadsheet linked above,  how do I Send an email when the "Repair Completed column" is marked yes. The email would be sent to the email addresses in the third,fourth and fifth column and would include the customers name which it would get from the first column. Also once the email has been sent I would like a "email sent" message in the last column of the spreadsheetwith the date and time the email was sent. Also how do I have an email sent when the date retuned date in my spreadsheet is not filled in after 6 weeks?

Comment: It looks that you should start from the basics as the code has several errors but you didn't include any error message. i.e. on the line `for (i in UserData) {` UserData isn't defined but few lines later it's defined, but as Cooper already mentioned `range` isn't defined.

Comment: @ruben I have now modified the script to the one above. I am trying to now send to more than one receipient and make the script work on a timed trigger rather than an edit trigger.

Comment: @copper I have now modified the script to the one above in the question. I am trying to now send to more than one receipient and make the script work on a timed trigger rather than an edit trigger.